# How to access the declare specifications of a function

Tags: declare

How does one access the `declare` specification of a function?

**Edit:** After the answer of [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) I have to correct myself.

<strike>As long as a function is not byte-compiled the `declare` forms are still in its `symbol-function`. Where do they go after byte-compilation?</strike>

Example: (content of scratch buffer with lisp code and evaluation results)

```lisp
(defun test (&rest args)
  "Function with declare form."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (interactive)
  (message args))
;; repl: test

(symbol-function 'test)
;; repl: (lambda (&rest args) "Function with declare form." (interactive) (message args))

(symbol-plist 'test)
;; repl: (lisp-indent-function 1)
```

That means the `declare` forms are not contained in the function cell of the symbol after the `defun`.

```
(defun test (&rest args)
  "Function with declare form."
  (interactive)
  (declare (indent 1))
  (message args))

(symbol-function 'test)
(lambda (&rest args) "Function with declare form." (interactive) (declare (indent 1)) (message args))

(setf f (byte-compile 'test))
#[(&rest args) "\301!\207" [args message] 2 "Function with declare form." nil]
```

What is the right way to access the declare information of a function in elisp?

Comment: Good question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you have the `declare` in the wrong place, it should go before `(interactive)`:

```el
(defun test (&rest args)
  "Function with declare form."
  (declare (indent 1))
  (interactive)
  (message args))
```

Then if you macroexpand you can see what it does:

```el
(prog1
    (defalias 'test
      #'(lambda
          (&rest args)
          "Function with declare form."
          (interactive)
          (message args)))
  (put 'test 'lisp-indent-function '1))
```

As you can see, the `declare` form itself is not stored, but `defun` interprets and rewrites it into code with the needed effect.  Also note that the effect works on the symbol, not the function itself.

To reconstruct a `declare` form you would have to see what each kind of declaration does; the effects are listed in `defun-declarations-alist` and `macro-declarations-alist` (you can see this by looking at the definitions of `defun` and `defmacro`).  Almost all work by `put`ting a property on the symbol, so you could just `get` the corresponding property.  The only exception (as of Emacs 24.5) is `advertised-calling-convention` which stores the preferred signature in `advertised-signature-table`, a hash table with the function itself as the key.

Comment: And a good answer.

Comment: This is almost the right answer and I will mark it as such primarily because of its simplicity. You ask: "Why the 'almost'?" Because the information could be stored at some other place, e.g., an hash-table that captures all functions with `declare` forms. The right path to go is to look at `defmacro`, `defun` and most important `defun-declarations-alist` where the function properties and their actions are defined. Maybe, it is even possible to reconstruct the `declare` forms via the comparison of the symbol properties with the elements of `defun-declarations-alist`. Difficult: (e.g., `debug`).

Comment: @Tobias ah, good point about `defun-declarations-alist`, I added some info about that to the answer. `debug` is not more difficult than the other declarations though.